# How to register ASP.NET 4.0 for IIS using PowerShell Web Administration module?

Tags: asp.net, iis, powershell-3.0, aspnet-regiis.exe, web-administration

I would like to register the ASP.NET 4.0 framework for IIS using a PowerShell script. I have previously used the aspnet_regiis.exe tool in the following way:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe –iru
```

This did the job, but I would like to refactor my code to use the PowerShell WebAdministration module to do this configuration. I already used it in my script to configure other things in IIS and I want to keep the sourcecode consistent.

There is a way to do this config. step using the WebAdministration module? I looked for the cmdlets from WebAdministration module, but I can't figure out which one could do the trick. Anyone could help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows Server 2008 R2 and above then you can use the PowerShell Server Manager module to install ASP.NET

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Add-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net
```

Resources:

http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-85/installing-iis-85-on-windows-server-2012-r2#ModulesinIIS85

http://tech.toptable.co.uk/blog/2013/06/14/windows-feature-management-with-powershell/